# Read links from a list from a txt file - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file named links.txt which contains the following list 
(List name : Set_of_links) :

[https://link1.com, https://link2.com, https://link3.com/hello, https://links4.com/index.php, . . . . ]

I'm executing the program, links_python.py which needs to read each link from that file and store it in a local variable in the python script. I'm using the following program :

```
i = 0
with open(links.txt, "r") as f:
    f.read(set_of_links[i])
    i+=1
```

Seems to be not working.

Comment: try `set_of_links[i]  = f.read()`

Comment: Can you provide a better example of your input file? In a code box please.

Comment: If you can define the input format of the data, then can I suggest you put the data in to JSON format. Then you can use the built in JSON parse to convert the file to python lists/dictionaries.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight something like that but not `f.read()` rather `f.readline()` or the first pass reads the file fully and the other values are empty.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only 1 line of links, throw away the brackets and spaces and try

```
links = []
with open('links.txt')) as f:
    links = f.read().split(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following : Thanks to @Jean for the edit

```
i = 0
with open(links.txt, "r") as f:
    set_of_links[i] = f.readline()
    i+=1
```

Comment: I think `set_of_links.append` is more pythonic. Then you can take away the `i` variable.

Comment: `set_of_links = [l.rstrip() for l in f]` would be even better. but I'm unsure of OP input format.

Comment: This will not separate each link and append it to the list as stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to separate each link and append it to `set_of_links` you can use `re` to substitute these characters `[],` then create the list by splitting. Using list comprehensions it should look like:

```
import re
with open('links.txt', 'r') as f:
    set_of_links = [re.sub(r'[(\[\],)]', '', x) for x in f.read().split()]
    print set_of_links
```

output:

```
['https://link1.com', 'https://link2.com', 'https://link3.com/hello', 'https://links4.com/index.php']
```